how can I color each bar in my am5charts horizontal bar chart?
I am using NUXT 3, Please help, I am trying to color each bar in my horizontal am5chart, I get:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown color syntax: #FF5733,#33FF57,#337AFF,#FF33F5,#FFCA33,#33FFCA
at _Color.fromAny
Here is the code I am using:
const colors = ["#FF5733", "#33FF57", "#337AFF", "#FF33F5", "#FFCA33", "#33FFCA"];
    // Create series (horizontal columns)
    const series1 = chart.series.push(
        am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
            name: "Series",
            xAxis: xAxis,
            yAxis: yAxis,
            valueXField: "value1", // Use valueXField instead of valueYField
            categoryYField: "category", // Use categoryYField instead of categoryXField
            fill: am5.color(colors),
        })
    );
    series1.data.setAll(data);

